# Why isn't Spring kicking in the JSR-303 bean validation?

Tags: spring, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, spring-framework-beans, jakarta-validation

Wondering why Spring is not getting the Hibernate Bean Validation kicked in. According to the documentation [HERE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/validation/beanvalidation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-method), it requires a `MethodValidationPostProcessor` in the context and the target spring bean to be annotated with `@Validated` annotation. I got both of these requirements done, but it is still not working.

I expected an exception at the call to `backgroundCheck` method due to the fact that the person's name is `null` and the age is less than 18. For some reason, however, the `Person` object is not being validated and the method finishes without exceptions.

Here is my setup:

```
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        methodValidationPostProcessor.setValidator(validator());
        return methodValidationPostProcessor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {

        PersonService personService = new PersonService();

        try {
            personService.backgroundCheck(new Person(null, 4));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("<<< EXCEPTION >>>");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("<<< NO VALIDATIONS THROWN >>>");
    }
}
```

```
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@Validated
@Service
public class PersonService {

    public void backgroundCheck(@Valid Person person) {
        System.out.printf("Running background check for %s%n", person.name());
    }
}
```

```
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Min;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

public record Person(
        @NotBlank(message = "Name must not be blank")
        String name,

        @Min(value = 18, message = "Age should not be less than 18")
        int age) {
}
```

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>21</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated` **@Validated** must be a **Spring Bean** to perform validation.

  - This is an AOP-based method that intercepts and processes method requests.
  - Therefore, validation can be performed on any Spring bean regardless of the hierarchy such as controller, service, or repository.
- The problem is that the code simply creates and uses a PersonService instance.

  - Currently, PersonService created through the new keyword is not a Spring Bean.
  - So @Validated also has no effect.
- In the code below, I will change the code to make it work as expected.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        methodValidationPostProcessor.setValidator(validator());
        return methodValidationPostProcessor;
    }
    // register spring bean!
    @Bean
    public PersonService personService() {
        return new PersonService();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {

        try {
            personService().backgroundCheck(new Person(null, 4));
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
            System.out.println("<<< EXCEPTION >>>");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("<<< NO VALIDATIONS THROWN >>>");
    }
}
```

#### Result.

```java
2024-03-20T13:09:23.676+09:00  INFO 4384 --- [           main]
<<< EXCEPTION >>>
```

- ConstraintViolationException occurred normally.

I hope it will be of help :) thanks.